# Conflict for property svn:ignore?

Tags: svn

How do I resolve a conflict for the `svn:ignore` property?

I ignored some files in my local repository using the below command:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

When I ran `svn update`, I saw the below conflict:

```
Conflict for property 'svn:ignore' discovered on ''
```

When I run `svn diff`, I see the below differences:

```
Property changes on: .
___________________________________________________________________
Modified: svn:ignore
   -

   + cache/*
log/*
```

How can I resolve this conflict? I want to remove my local modifications for `svn ignore`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File attributes are just like the contents of a file in Subversion. They too require a *commit* to be modified and can be in conflict.

Do an `svn status` and you'll see more of a description of the conflict. There are three possibilities:

- **Incoming edit and local edit**: Both you and the previous version edited this attribute. Should have been able to do a merge.
- **Incoming add and local add**: You added this attribute, and so did someone else.
- **Incoming delete and local edit or add**: A revision wars -- this attribute was in a previous revision of the repository, and that person deleted this attribute. You've edited it.

There are two ways to solve this issue:

- Do a revert on this attribute. If you added it, do a `svn propdel --force` on it. Because this is a directory, don't do a `svn revert .` because you'll revert all the changes in this directory. you don't want to do that. Just revert this attribute. You maybe able to revert just the attribute by doing a `svn revert --depth=empty` . I never tried that.
- Do a `svn resolved .`. This will mark the conflict in `.` as resolved. It's not necessarily resolved, but you can at least mark it as such and fix it later.

If you reverted the property change, and resolved the conflict that way, do an `svn update` and reedit the property. If you did an `svn resolved .` on the conflict, then take a look at the value of the previous revision by doing a `svn propget -rPREV svn:ignore .`. This way, you can see what the previous revision set it to, and take that into account. It could be a simplle ordering issue. For example, the previous revision set it to:

```
target
build.properties
```

You set it to:

```
build.properties
target
```

In the end, both are the same value. Or, it could be that the previous revision had a directory of file name in there that you didn't have. For example, it was set to:

```
*.log
```

and you set it to:

```
build.properties
target
```

You probably want to set it to:

```
build.properties
target
*.log
```

First *resolve* the conflict, do an *update*, and then set it to the value you need.

Comment: When doing: `svn propdel svn:ignore --force` I received the error: `Subcommand 'propdel' doesn't accept option '--force'` I removed --force and was able to continue with the steps to resolve this issue. Perhaps we have different versions of Subversion. In my case I am on version 1.6.11

Answer (score 1):

`svn:ignore` is a property of the *parent* folder that contains the files you have set to be ignored. It is that folder, therefore, that is exhibiting a conflict.

**Plan A**
The easiest solution is to delete that containing folder then do an SVN update to restore it as it exists in the repository.

**Plan B**
If deleting the folder is not an option for you for some reason (e.g. if you have some modified files you want to keep) then rename the folder (e.g. to `yourfolder-TEMP`) and again do an SVN update. This recreates `yourfolder` with no conflict in the svn properties. Now copy back the files you need from `yourfolder-TEMP` to `yourfolder` and then delete the old folder once you are satisfied you have preserved what you need.

Comment: This is by far the most practical way to solve this type of conflict.