# Conflicted directory subversion in Eclipse (svn:ignore file?)

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I have a conflicted directory. See **dmwf-parent** :

[image]

Firstly i would like to know what that means. It seems like there are no files inside this directory that have changed.

If I go to **Edit Conflicts** I see this :

[image]

So does this mean that someone else has set some other files to svn:ignore compared to what I have? And why do I not see the file in conflict in subversion? Is it because its a SVN ignore file that it does not show in the original conflict tree?

Finally what should I do to get rid of it? Should i just somehow merge the file? But there is no option to merge a file as far as I can see.

Comment: `svn:ignore` is not a file. It is a meta information on a directory. So the conflict is indeed on the directory, but does not refer to the content (its files) but to its meta info. This conflict simply means that someone else had entered (or changed) the ignore info with other data than you have locally. You now have to resolve that locally. Some info: Your ignored files indicate that you are using Eclipse. The other ignored file indicates that someone is using Netbeans. So I would suggest to simply merge all those entries.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983606/conflict-for-property-svnignore) has a good answer that explains what's happening. If you haven't too many property changes, I think you can update and the re-apply your changes and commit.

Comment: good answer. why don't you put it as an answer to the question?

Comment: @OliverWatkins You are right, so I did that now. I started my comment as an explanation for what `svn:ignore` is but it somehow mutated into an actual answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

`svn:ignore` is not a file. It is a meta information on a directory.

So the conflict is indeed on the directory, but does not refer to the content (its files) but to its meta info. This conflict simply means that someone else had entered (or changed) the ignore info with other data than you have locally.

You now have to resolve that locally. Some info: Your ignored files indicate that you are using Eclipse. The other ignored file indicates that someone is using Netbeans. So I would suggest to simply merge all those entries.